# Generating the outter convex polygon

Tags: math, geometry, polygon, computational-geometry, mesh

I have the following set of points:

[image]

Basically, they're distinct points of many different rectangles. I'd love to merge them into a polygon like so, omitting the inner vertices:

[image]

I've tried generating a polygon with a simple sort by the angle to the center of the shape but failed miserably, as it appears I'd have to get rid of the inner not needed vertices first. Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: This "outter polygon" is not convex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by contour tracing, 4-connected neighborhood.

http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/downloads_V3/root_downloads/tutorials/contour_tracing_Abeer_George_Ghuneim/index.html